# Listview and 2nd xml

Tags: android, android-listview, simpleadapter

I have a list_view_row xml file.
The list_view_row.xml contains editText boxes, i want to use them to display the items (collected by a SimpleAdapter) in the listbox in my main program (Android.java).
Eclipse won`t let me compile the code as i need to declare these editText boxes in Android.java

```
 int[] to = new int[] { R.id.editText1, R.id.editText1 };
```

How do i do that?
Thank you in advance.

The list_view_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:width="100dp" 
  android:height="100dp"
>

<EditText> 
 android:inputType="textMultiLine"  
 android:id="@+id/editText1"  
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:text="edit1"  
 android:layout_width="110dp"> 
</EditText>  

<EditText> 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:layout_width="110dp"  
 android:id="@+id/editText2"  
 android:text="edit2" 
 android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
 android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" 
</EditText> 

</LinearLayout>
```

The code in main.xml:

```
@Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
        //publishProgress(false); 
        // create the grid item mapping
        ListView kp = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.kpn);

        String[] from = new String[] {"col_1", "col_2"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.editText1, R.id.editText1 }; <<< ??????????

        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(kpn);
        Elements tdsFromSecondColumn = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(0)");
        Elements tdsFromSecondColumn1 = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(1)"); 

        for (Element tdFromSecondColumn : tdsFromSecondColumn) {
            map.put("col_1", tdFromSecondColumn.text()); 
            fillMaps.add(map);

            System.out.println("Hashmap: " + map);
            System.out.println(tdFromSecondColumn.text()); 

        } 
        for (Element tdFromSecondColumn1 : tdsFromSecondColumn1) {
            map.put("col_2", tdFromSecondColumn1.text());
            fillMaps.add(map);

            System.out.println("Hashmap: " + map);
            System.out.println(tdFromSecondColumn1.text());
        }

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AndroidLogin.this, fillMaps, R.layout.list_view_row, from, to); 
        kp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Lars, you're getting a lot better at asking questions. Good work! :)

Comment: Hi Kurtis,
Yes, i`m trying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is incorrect, here is the correct format:

```
<EditText android:inputType="textMultiLine"  
 android:id="@+id/editText1"  
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:text="edit1"  
 android:layout_width="110dp"/>
```

Once you correct this, build your project and the R.id.editText1 and R.id.editText2 should be recognized in code.

EDIT: Hint - go to your Project menu at the top, and then down to "Build Automatically." This will cause your project to build upon saving a file (java / xml). After you modify the XML, and save, it will build and make your editText1 resource available to access by R.id.editText1.

Comment: Hi Jack,
Thx it worked, is there any explanation why i have to use the closing tag /> instead of </EditText> ?
I`ll have to work on the code from the SimpleAdapter as it not correctly displays the items, edit1 only contains the last value of the map 0,00 and edit2 contains nothing.

Comment: I think it is because on items that will not have any children (edittext, textview, etc...) there is no need for a full closing tag. It would probably still work if you changed "110dp" /> to "110dp" ></EditText>